# Eclipse Autocomplete for PHP Extensions?

Tags: php, eclipse, autocomplete

I just downloaded and installed the [Gearman](http://gearman.org/) extension for PHP, and would really like to have autocomplete work for this in Eclipse.

I've been searching through preferences and googling for hours but I haven't been able to come up with anything. I've tried restarting Eclipse as well as adding the php.net manual for Gearman. Nothing seems to make to enable autocomplete or tooltips for Gearman.

Anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can view http://www.php-editors.com/review/anjuta.htm its best suited for Web Development Purpose. Also its Eclipse Based. Might Fulfill your requirement.